# Creating a slideshow with images embedded in a cellphone, as if they are screenshots

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am trying to create an image slideshow.  The images will be screenshots of an android cell phone, then i want an actual picture of a cell phone to cycle through these images as if they were what is showing on the phone.

So it would be a cell phone slideshow with images of an application.

Any help on this would be great.  I am able to create a simple slideshow with three images changing every 2 seconds, but i just want these images to be on top of a cell phone image.

here is what i have so far:

Answer (score 0):

Yu need an image of a cellphone with the screen portion cut out. Save out the phone as a PNG file so the screen cutout portion becomes transparent. Then you need to place the PNG in the HTML document. And give the PNG a class with styles properties

```
position: absolute;
width: xxx px;
height:xxx px;
top:xxx px;
left:xxx px;
z-index: 2;
```

Obviously adjust the xxx values above to your asset and positions on screen. Basically the partially transparent PNG will sit over the slides with the correct z index. Increase the z index as you need.